# Group objects according with their (x0, x1) and (y0, y1) coordinates | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tree, siblings

I have an array of objects:

```
elements: [
    {id: 1, type: "rectangle", x: 10, y: 10, w: 100, h: 60},
    {id: 2, type: "rectangle", x: 200, y: 30, w: 100, h: 100},
    {id: 3, type: "rectangle", x: 400, y: 0, w: 300, h: 200},
    {id: 4, type: "rectangle", x: 10, y: 10, w: 100, h: 60},
    {id: 5, type: "rectangle", x: 150, y: 30, w: 100, h: 100},
    {id: 6, type: "rectangle", x: 150, y: 270, w: 300, h: 60},
]
```

I need to go through each object and group them according to their coordinates. The goal is to group them vertically (add rows) and horizontally (add columns).

From those objects I need to get this:

```
filteredElements: [
    {id: 1, type: "row", parent_id: null, data: {}},
    {id: 2, type: "row", parent_id: null, data: {}},
    {id: 3, type: "column", parent_id: 1, data: {marginLeft: ?, marginTop: ?}},
    {id: 4, type: "column", parent_id: 1, data: {marginLeft: ?, marginTop: ?}},
    {id: 5, type: "column", parent_id: 1, data: {marginLeft: ?, marginTop: ?}},
    {id: 6, type: "rectangle", parent_id: 3, data: {x: 10, y: 10, w: 100, h: 60,}},
    {id: 7, type: "rectangle", parent_id: 4, data: {x: 200, y: 30, w: 100, h: 100,}},
    {id: 8, type: "rectangle", parent_id: 5, data: {x: 400, y: 0, w: 300, h: 200,}},
    {id: 9, type: "row", parent_id: 8, data: {}},
    {id: 10, type: "column", parent_id: 9, data: {marginLeft: ?, marginTop: ?}},
    {id: 11, type: "column", parent_id: 9, data: {marginLeft: ?, marginTop: ?}},
    {id: 12, type: "rectangle", parent_id: 10, data: {x: 10, y: 10, w: 100, h: 60,}},
    {id: 13, type: "rectangle", parent_id: 11, data: {x: 150, y: 30, w: 100, h: 100,}},
    {id: 14, type: "rectangle", parent_id: 2, data: {x: 150, y: 270, w: 300, h: 60,}},
]
```

Please note that some "rectangles" might be inside others making them children.

So, I need to:

- check how many rows a column has (starting with the root)
- check how many columns a row has
- define the parent_id according to the hierarchy of the objects
- define the type of the new object (row or column?)
- add left and right margin to column according to parent and siblings

Here's a visual example of what is pretended:
[visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfcfM.png)

I understand this is more of a mathematical challenge but I'm not being able to wrap my brain on it.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

**EDIT**:

Here is my current logic for calculating columns:

```js
elements: [{
    id: 1,
    type: "rectangle",
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    w: 100,
    h: 60
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "rectangle",
    x: 200,
    y: 30,
    w: 100,
    h: 100
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: "rectangle",
    x: 400,
    y: 0,
    w: 300,
    h: 200
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: "rectangle",
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    w: 100,
    h: 60
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    type: "rectangle",
    x: 150,
    y: 30,
    w: 100,
    h: 100
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    type: "rectangle",
    x: 150,
    y: 270,
    w: 300,
    h: 60
  },
]





for (var element of elements) {

  if (!inserted_first) var compare = {
    id: 1,
    type: "column",
    x0: element.x0,
    x1: element.x1,
    y0: element.y0,
    y1: element.y1,
    elements: []
  };
  inserted_first = true;

  index++;

  if (this.isBetween(element.x0, compare.x0, compare.x1)) {
    (element.x1 > compare.x1) ? compare = {
      type: "column",
      x0: compare.x0,
      x1: element.x1,
      y0: element.y0,
      y1: element.y1
    }: compare = {
      type: "column",
      x0: compare.x0,
      x1: compare.x1,
      y0: element.y0,
      y1: element.y1
    };
    if (index == length) this.pushCompareArray(compare, compare_index, destiny_array);

  } else if (this.isOutside(element.x1, compare.x1, compare.x0)) {
    (element.x0 < compare.x0) ? compare = {
      type: "column",
      x0: element.x0,
      x1: compare.x1,
      y0: element.y0,
      y1: element.y1
    }: compare = {
      type: "column",
      x0: compare.x0,
      x1: compare.x1,
      y0: element.y0,
      y1: element.y1
    };
    if (index === length) this.pushCompareArray(compare, compare_index, destiny_array);

  } else {
    compare.id = compare_index;
    compare.elements = [];
    destiny_array.push(compare);
    compare = {
      type: "column",
      x0: element.x0,
      x1: element.x1,
      y0: element.y0,
      y1: element.y1
    };
    compare_index++;
    if (index === length) this.pushCompareArray(compare, compare_index, destiny_array);
    compare = {
      type: "column",
      x0: element.x0,
      x1: element.x1,
      y0: element.y0,
      y1: element.y1
    };
  }
}
```

I feel this can be simplified...

Comment: what are your efforts?

Comment: @UllasHunka I'm using an aux array to add the min and max of the objects. Let me know if you'd like to see the code

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: @UllasHunka DONE. I've added the logic to calculate columns.